# Android- wifiDirect

Tags: android

I am developing a simple wifiDirect chat app.My app does peer searching and once peer's list is available one can select a particular device, the one to connect with. Then my code calls `connect()` which sends a notification to the other device (2nd phone) about connection (default). Once the second phone agrees to the connection then 1st phone becomes group owner while second phone running my app does nothing.

So my question is do I need to call `connect()` on both devices? Also when is this intent action `WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast?
Need help, read android.developers.com and other official sites but couldn't figure out.

Comment: you will need to call the connect () only once when discovery request is broadcasted to all the listeners. Since, the same code runs on both the devices, you will be able to create socket connection and then can exchange messages using this connection.

Answer (score 0):

No, you only need to call `connect()` on one device. Note that this does not mean that the device that calls `connect()` will be the group owner. The system will decide the group owner itself. You can only suggest your preference through `config.groupOwnerIntent = x;` where x is from 0 to 15, 0 representing least intention to become owner while 15 represents the highest.

`WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION` event will be fired when the status of the device has changed.

Use the following code to fetch the updated details of the device.

```
(WifiP2pDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));
```